# D'Alemberts formula with both initial value and derivative equal to 0

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Trying to solve a PDE problem consisting of these equations:

$$ u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx} = 0 \quad \quad(0 < x < L, t > 0)$$
$$u(0,t), \quad u(L,t)=Bsin(\omega_{0}t) \quad (t >0)$$
$$u(x,0) = 0, \quad u_{t}(x,0) = 0 \quad (0 < x < L)$$

$C,L,B,\omega_{0} > 0$ are constants

I know that the general solution to the wave equation is
$$u(x,t) = \phi(x+ct)+\psi(x-ct)$$

And I have d'Alembert's forumla. The problem is that since these initial values are on the standard form, d'Alembert's should apply, right? But $u(x,0) = u_{t}(x,0) = 0$, giving that u(x,t) = 0 as well, which cannot be right. I can't even get to the point where the second row of I.V is relevant (u(0,t) and u(L,t)).

Is there something fundamental I am missing with the wave equation and d'Alembert? Is there a reason why d'Alembert would not apply here? Would appreciate any help on those questions so that I can try and actually solve the question by myself.

Comment: Nope, this is completely consistent. If the initial position and initial velocity of a particle, say, are both zero, it will remain at zero.

Answer (score 1):

The d'Alembert formula solves the Cauchy problem for wave equation, but you have first mixed problem, and you should use another methods such as Laplace transform or separation of variables. You can also build a solution using general form of solution.

In this problem the d'Alembert formula, which implies $u \equiv 0$, correct only in triangle $(0,0)$ -- $(L, 0)$ -- $(L/2, L/(2a))$, because you have the Cauchy problem in this triangle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can understand why it only applies in (0,0)--(L,0), and that the solution can be something else outside that boundary, but why is the 3rd point (L/2,L/(2a))? Will try with variable separation and Laplace as well, thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I read up on the Domain of Dependence and Region of Influence which provided the answer, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!